# How to send data to backend in Ion-input with a (change) event

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'll use the image below for my illustration. I am trying to get data from the backend when a user enter a value into a textbox and click outside it triggers an event that will fetch value from the backend and populate the second textbox.

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty general question. What have you tried? Which back-end? Look at the ion-input events https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#events

Comment: @TomasVancoillie MySQL